# Transform UV map when running python script in background

Tags: python, scripting, uv, uv-image-editor

I'm trying to rotate, resize and translate an UV map using a python script that runs in the background (without UI). I got it working when running the script directly in blender (with UI) but cannot get it to run in the background. The main issue is that I am trying to access the 'UV' area, but that is not possible since I am not using the UI. So my question is, how can i access the UV editor when running the python script in the background and apply the transforms?

Below I've attached a code snippet of what I want to run in the background.

```
# Enter UV mode
bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()  
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')
last_area = bpy.context.area.type
bpy.context.area.ui_type = 'UV'
bpy.ops.uv.select_all(action='SELECT')
# Apply transformations
bpy.ops.transform.rotate(value=math.radians(90), orient_axis='Z')
bpy.ops.transform.resize(value=(2.0, 2.0, 1.0))
bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(100.0, 100.0, 0.0))
# Exit UV mode
bpy.context.area.type = last_area
bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
```

Comment: If you're in the background there is, as you point out, no UI; so you can't access the UV Editor, just as you couldn't use a context to override it if you didn't have a UV editor window open in the interface. But you don't enter the UV editor by toggling edit mode, anyway. That just changes the mode of the 3D Viewport.  I think you need to look into image manipulation operations to accomplish what you want.